# Is it possible to upload to OneDrive via Terminal on Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, external-hard-drive, onedrive, testdisk

So I want to make a .dd copy file from my external HDD using TestDisk and I do not have 1 TB free on my MacBook, but I do on my OneDrive account. Is it possible to make the .dd copy directly on my OneDrive account?

Comment: Even if this was possible, you would have to create the local file first, before you could upload it to OneDrive

Comment: Yes, I didn't say well in the title. I mean if it's a command or something to make a virtual folder of the OneDrive that uploads bit by bit to the account